# What is wrong with this return statement?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, tslint

```
return state$.select(state => {
     return state.user.access_token !== ''});
```

This is the error i am getting,

> [tslint] Missing Semicolon (semicolon)

Comment: Either do this `return state$.select(state => state.user.access_token !== '');` or `return state$.select(state => { return state.user.access_token !== ''; });`. Don't mix up.

Comment: The error you are getting is specific to your tslint rules, not your return statement. You are missing a semicolon after your second return

Comment: stackoverflow encourages users to ask questions in a way that makes them helpful to future readers: *"what is wrong with this return statement?"* is an awful question because it's unlikely to be of any relevance to anyone but you.

Answer (score 3):

Add a semicolon:

```
return state$.select(state => {
    return state.user.access_token !== '';
});
```

Or just do:

```
return state$.select(state => state.user.access_token !== '');
```